# Configure pacemaker's src addr

Tags: pacemaker, corosync

I'm trying to configure my corosync cluster with 2 ips:
 - 1 public
 - 1 private

I do have 3 primitives:
 - 2 ipaddr2 to mount ips
 - 1 ipsrcaddr to src from the private ip in it's subnet

My problem is that ipsrcaddr replaces the default gateway with my private address as source, like this:
~# ip r s
default via 92.181.55.1 dev ens3 src 192.168.0.11
92.181.55.1 dev ens3 scope link
192.168.0.0/24 dev ens4 scope link via 192.168.0.11

I can no longer send traffic with my public ip after resource starts :/

Anyone experienced the same issue ? Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: I removed proto kernel here:https://github.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/blob/master/heartbeat/IPsrcaddr#L476

Comment: And i added a parameter to execute this or not: https://github.com/ClusterLabs/resource-agents/blob/master/heartbeat/IPsrcaddr#L178